# Предпоказ нескольких изображений

Tags: reactjs

Хочу сделать предпоказ изображений добавляемых через `input type="file"`

Но если выбрать несколько изображений, то загружается только одно из них.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
const [image, setImage] = React.useState([]) 
const [previewImg, setPreviewImg] = React.useState([])

React.useEffect(() => {
    let data = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {

    let reader = new FileReader()
    reader.readAsDataURL(image[i])

    reader.addEventListener('load', () => {
        data.push(reader.result);

        setPreviewImg(data);
    })
    }

}, [image])

<input onChange={(e) => setImage(e.target.files)} type="file" accept='image/*' multiple />
```

Если снова нажать на выбор файлов и потом закрыть, то отображаются все выбранные.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Т.к. вы не создали минимальный рабочий пример, могу лишь предположить что проблема в строке `setPreviewImg(data)` - у вас при добавлении новых данных ссылка не изменяется и react не видит изменений массива.

Попробуйте изменить эту строку на `setPreviewImg([...data])`

Хотя я написал бы всё по другому:

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"

function Demo() {
  const [files, setFiles] = useState([])
  const [previewImg, setPreviewImg] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    setPreviewImg([...files].map(file => URL.createObjectURL(file)))
  }, [files])

  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={(e) => setFiles(e.target.files)} type="file" accept='image/*' multiple />
      {previewImg.map((url, i) => <img width={100} height={100} key={i} src={url} />)}
    </div>
  )
}
```